# How to get distribution name from scipy.stats.distribution object in SciPy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, distribution

I'm trying out a bunch of different fits for distributions.

Is there any way to get the name of the distribution back from the distribution object?

I found a way but it doesn't seem very efficient.

```
distribution = "gamma"
distr = getattr(stats, distribution)
print(distr)
# <scipy.stats._continuous_distns.gamma_gen object at 0x11688f518>
str(distr).split(".")[3].split("_")[0]
# 'gamma'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `name` attribute:

```
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> distribution = "gamma"
>>> distr = getattr(stats, distribution)
>>> distr.name
'gamma'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `name` attribute:

```
from scipy import stats
print(stats.gamma.name)
```